# What to spend your credits on in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm not that far through, and I'm already up to like 40k credits... and simply I don't know what to spend this on.

Things I would really like to buy are stun ammo, but I can't find anywhere that sells them, and then I would like to buy tranq darts, but again, I can't find anywhere to buy them. LIMB buildings only have 2 praxis kits and seem to sell out.

Plus I would like to buy those bars that give me energy, but can't find anywhere either. 
It seems like the game has not given me any way to spend my credits.

Comment: Maybe Adam is just saving for a vacation?

Comment: That's normal. If you do a lot of side quests, you'll have more money than you know what to do with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What to spend money on depends a lot on play style, but here are my suggestions, in priority order:

1. You need $50,000 to buy Praxis kits, period. Just make sure you have $10k available when you enter a new area; don't expect to have it all immediately.
2. General weapon mods, because they will always be useful. You don't really need more than three silencers or laser sights, however; there are only so many weapons to attach them to before your weapon choices start to get redundant.
3. EMP grenades, up to three or four, for bots, turrets, and cameras.
4. Energy bars, if they are for sale. The jar is very wasteful of inventory space, so I never buy any.
5. Special weapon mods, the ones that attach to only one or two specific named weapons. You often don't need to buy them, however; you can find them during normal exploration.

If you don't care about Ghost XP bonuses...

1. All the other kinds of grenades.
2. Ammunition, only if there is *one* weapon that you constantly use heavily. The most likely candidates are the Tranquilizer Rifle, Stun Gun, and Rocket Launcher; ammo for any of the three is rare, and there is no way you'll be able to use any of them as primary weapons without purchasing ammo.

The only weapon I ever thought about buying was the crossbow, because there seem to only be a handful in the game.

As a side note, mines and mine templates are very useful at the end of your first visit to Tai Yong Medical.

And if you are thinking that the game does not have enough ways to spend credits, you're right. Just use that as an excuse to be relatively free with them.

Comment: EMPing cameras doesn't trigger alarms.

Comment: Good to know. Shooting them seems to.

Comment: Wonder what stun gun does to them?

Comment: @Raven IIRC it just puts them to sleep for a short period of time, with no alarm triggered. I used the trick at least once to give me more time to hack something that a camera kept sweeping over.

Comment: @Raven, DMA: Apparently the stun gun does this to turrets and box guards as well; that is its main advantage over the tranquilizer rifle. I wish I'd known this before completely writing it off, but it's almost always easier to get around electronic adversaries because there are simply fewer of them.

Answer (score 3):

In order to buy all the Praxis kits LIMB has to offer, you're going to need 50K in credits.

Then there's stuff in-game like bribes et cetera which might make stuff easier.

Everything on top of that can only be spent on weapons, ammo and CyberBoost items LIMB sells.

Answer (score 2):

I'm shocked nobody did mention alcohol...

On the more serious note, if you have enough spare time, you can actually spent all of your money on drinks.

Answer (score 0):

The only white market vendor I have seen in the game is the LIMB Clinic. Other than that, you have to go with the limited stocks of the Black Market vendors. I've got 30K myself and have bought a every mod I can use and still have a lot of money.

**TL;DR**: No, your limited to LIMB and your friendly neighborhood arms dealer.

Comment: Little bit annoying, would like to buy the energy bars to get bonus energy

Comment: @Layke - you can buy them from LIMB.

Comment: Yeah, LIMB has a few.